# How can I avoid automatic deallocate in C++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, scope

A `CertificateInfo` has some `CStrings and some`CTimes`.

When execution reaches the closing brace of CheckCertificates it breaks execution because of a corruption of the heap. The last call stack frame is
`CSWizard.exe!_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(const void * pUserData=0x00ba8e08)` from deallocating `aCertificates`.

```
    typedef vector<CertificateInfo> CertificateArray;

    CertificateArray CertificateStore::CollectCertificatesInfo(CertificateArray &ca, 
                                                               bool bExpirationDateOnly /* = false */,
                                                               bool bCertSignOnly /* = true */)
    {
        CertificateArray aCertificates;

         while(Precondition())
         {
             CertificateInfo ci;
             if(Condition(ci))
             {
                 aCertificates.push_back(ci);
             }
         }

         return aCertificates;
    }

    void CSWizardApp::CheckCertificates(bool bOnDemand)
    {
        PersonalStore store;
        CertificateArray aCertificates;

        aCertificates = store.CollectCertificatesInfo();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

What I noticed was that, for 1 `CertificateInfo` returned in the `CertificateArray`, the constructor will be called once, while the destructors of the `CertificateInfo` fields will be called 3 times.

Comment: Copy constructors are involved. Correcly define them in the `CertificateArray` class.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to "guess" what the problem is, and trying to find a solution to your guess, rather than actually fixing the underlying problem - which is that something is messed up in your design - in particular in relation to copying your content.

Comment: instead of disabling automatic deallocation, aka raii, you should debug the real reason of the crash...

Comment: @MatsPetersson I wasn't trying to guess, but to give relevant details about the problem.

Comment: I will try defining the copy constructors and see if it works that way, thank you, @avakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there are a couple of things you need to be careful of.

You declare `ca` as a parameter of the function, you also declare it as a variable locally. What this means is that when you call `ca.push_back(ci)`, you're actually trying to do an insert in to the local version.

Later on you try and return `ca` - which you do by value. This is normally fine but just be aware that the compiler will kind of not really return a copy (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) for some more details) that will contain a value (added with `ca.push_back(ci)`) that was created as a *copy* of the local version in that function.

It's hard to say more without knowing a little more about `CertificateInfo`. Does it contain a pointer `pUserData` that is cleared up in the destructor? If so, when you do the copy, if you don't have some logic to copy the heap data pointed to by that variable then when the function returns and the local version of `ci` is destroyed (taking the data associated with `pUserData` too if that's how the destructor is written) then the pointer in the *copy* that was returned will be invalid.

Does this help?

Comment: CertificateInfo doesn't have any field called pUserData, just CString's and CTime's.

Comment: I can understand that the local version of `ci` is destroyed, but how can I work around that?

Comment: The first obvious one is to create is on the heap and pass the pointer around, or better yet - use <code>boost::shared_ptr</code>. This does assume that the crash is happening as a result of the destuctor - that still isn't clear. You're going to have to look at exactly what the destructor is doing in Certificate info. It would probably help to look at the full stack of the crash and figure out exactly where/what is the crash is.

Comment: Yes, creating the objects on the heap worked. The destructor doesn't do anything, but I think it automatically called the destructors of the `CStrings` and `CTimes` and when it later needed to access them from `aCertificates` it would crash. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You are defining a local variable `ca` which hides the parameter `ca` you're passing in. Although this is not the only problem here, the code above almost certainly doesn't do what you expect it to do.

**EDIT:** As you've now disambiguated the local variable from the parameter:

- None of the parameters to `CollectCertificatesInfo` is used - is this intentional?
- As others have pointed out already, instances of `CertificateInfo` are being copied around a lot here, and its copy construction might be broken, but it's impossible to say that with certainty as you didn't give us any code for that class.

Comment: My bad, the local variable was named differently in the actual code. I changed it now.

Comment: So all parameters of `CollectCertificatesInfo` are unused?

Comment: Um, no. I've tried both creating the `CertificateArray` in `CollectCertificatesInfo` and passing `aCertificates` as parameter and push_back into it directly, so that's why I have it as a parameter, but I use the booleans in evaluating the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly lots of copies of `CertificateInfo` going on:

```
CertificateInfo ci; // 1st constructor
push_back(ci);      // 1st copy
return ca;          // 2nd copy
```

`Condition(ci)` might be another copy - how is `Condition` declared?

Ensure the copy ctr of CertificateInfo is correct.

Answer (score 0):

the code you posted is somewhat oversimplified: none of the parameters passed to *CollectCertificatesInfo()* are used, the only one could have been *ca*, but you redeclared it inside the function definition, thus preventing any access to the passed value.

I suppose that the *store* variable in the body of *CSWizardApp::CheckCertificates()* should be a *CertificateStore*, or maybe you're implying that *PersonalStore* is a subclass of *CertificateStore*?

I suggest you to clean your code a little or to complete it before asking for further help, because it's hard to figure out what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I used a *pointer* to a `CertificateArray` variable in `CertificateStore::CollectCertificatesInfo` instead of just a `CertificateArray`. This means the memory is allocated on the *heap*, instead of the stack. So, when execution gets out of `CertificateStore::CollectCertificatesInfo`, the memory on stack used for the function is cleared, but the memory allocated for the `CertificateInfo` objects, on the heap, is not deallocated, which makes sense :) . It's silly I didn't think about it earlier.

Thank you for your help, guys :)